# Long delay before view controller appears when using GCD and NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

Having odd behavior that I just can't figure out - when I'm pushing my second view controller onto a UINavigationController, there is a 5-10 second delay before the new view appears. The second view controller is being pushed based on an NSNotificationCenter notification.

The oddness: the delay only occurs when the event is posted from a background thread and not on the main thread (see comments in sample code below).

Why is there such a delay? This occurs on both simulator and device.

Here's the console output. As you can see, all logs appear in a timely manner, just not the 2nd view controller which suddenly appears after about 5-10 seconds.

```
2015-04-27 06:58:47.973 DelayedViews[49845:5005806] Background thread started
2015-04-27 06:58:49.978 DelayedViews[49845:5005806] Pushing second view controller
2015-04-27 06:58:49.979 DelayedViews[49845:5005806] Done pushing second view controller
2015-04-27 06:58:49.980 DelayedViews[49845:5005806] In completion block
2015-04-27 06:58:49.980 DelayedViews[49845:5005783] Back on main thread
```

And here's my simple example AppDelegate.m which demonstrates the issue.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navController;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

    UIViewController *vc = self.viewControllerOne;
    [self.navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    // register for notification center
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushSecondViewController) name:@"PushSecondVC" object:nil];

    // start background thread that posts notification and calls completion block

    void (^completion)() = ^void() {
        NSLog(@"In completion block");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Back on main thread");
                // If I do the notification here, the 2nd view controller is pushed immediately
                // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PushSecondVC" object:self];
        });
    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Background thread started");
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2]; // simulate some work

        // if the notification is posted here, there is a 5-10 second delay on simulator before second VC appears
        // even though the 2nd VC was pushed onto navigationcontroller.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PushSecondVC" object:self];

        // call completion block now
        completion();
    });


    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (UIViewController*)viewControllerOne {
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 100, 100, 100)];
    label.text = @"View #1";
    [vc.view addSubview:label];
    return vc;
}

- (UIViewController*)viewControllerTwo {
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200, 100, 100)];
    label.text = @"View #2";
    [vc.view addSubview:label];
    return vc;
}

- (void)pushSecondViewController {
    NSLog(@"Pushing second view controller");
    UIViewController *vc = self.viewControllerTwo;
    [self.navController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"Done pushing second view controller");
}

@end
```

Comment: If you verify the thread performing `pushSecondViewController` you'll most likely find out that that is a detached thread since the notification's been sent from detached thread, meaning you are basically performing a UI operation on a detached thread.

Comment: This could be because you are pushing  vcone and vctwo together. So untill vcone viewdidappear finishes execution vctwo wont' start its process. Also you have posted a thread sleep of 2 sec which also added to the delay.

Comment: @A-Live - you nailed it, thanks. @[Arun Gupta] the sleep is just to simulate the background operation. The second VC doesn't get pushed until after the 2-second sleep. At that point, there is a 5-10 second delay (see the NSLog output above which shows the timings for the methods/threads.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, A-Live, that appears to be it.

I changed the pushSecondViewController to the following and it seems to work perfectly now. I wonder what is going on under-the-covers and why it takes so long for the view to appear?

```
- (void)pushSecondViewController {
    if (![[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self pushSecondViewController];
        });
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Pushing second view controller");
    UIViewController *vc = self.viewControllerTwo;
    [self.navController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Done pushing second view controller");
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell precisely, but one would imagine there's a lot of optimisations based on lazy states, e.g. addition of a pending animation marks some flags as dirty and some scheduled verification triggers handling of pending changes. In general it just doesn't worth it to make everything thread-safe, design-driven usage contracts are much faster to implement and serve the cause pretty well.